# MVC: Relationship between UICollectionViewCell and an Object

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, uicollectionviewcell, nsobject

I have an object with a few properties (strings) I want the `UICollectionViewCell` to display. With regards to the MVC, is it better practice to set a property of the `UICollectionViewCell` to be the object and have the object setter update the UI, or would it be better directly update the UI in the Controller as `collectionView:cellFOrItemAtIndexPath:` is called?

Method A:

```
//
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
ACollectionViewCell *theCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
long fRow = [indexPath row];
theCell.objProp = self.itemArray[row]
return theCell;
}
```

in the viewcell

```
- (void)setObjProp:(myObj *)objProp
{
_objProp = objProp;
self.myLabel.text = objProp.name; 
...
}
```

Method B:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
FoodCollectionViewCell *theCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
long fRow = [indexPath row];


myObj *obj = self.itemArray[row];
theCell.myLabel.text = obj.name;
...
return theCell;
}
```

Comment: I would say 'B' as the delegate allows the code in question to act as the Controller and is fully MVC.